# Having Issues with external css linking

Tags: html, css

I just started getting into web design again and was practicing my skills to determine how much I remembered and ran into an issue along the way. the problem is that trying to connect link my external CSS to the HTML document, once I did that I when back to the CSS document and start changing an image's properties and nothing would change. Any help?

**HTML**
[image]

**CSS**
[image]

Comment: show us your code. not only pictures ...

Comment: You have made a typo it is `#Goku-img` instead of  `#goku-img` :).

Comment: add img tag to effected class in css file :

#goku-img img
{
width:20px
}

Answer (score 0):

## Goku-img img{

width : 20px
}

you should make sure your css selector matches a given id / class name in your html page. Css selectors are case sensitive.